# Wordpress: problem to insert a script in a post content

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, getelementbyid

I intend to insert the simple script below in a Wordpress **post content** through **Classic Editor**; but whenever I switch to visual mode or publish the post, Wordpress automatically removes the whole code (both HTML tags and script):

```
<p id="Test"></p>
<script>
var x = 10;
document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML= x;
</script>
```

To solve the issue, I followed these steps respectively:

**1)** The following snippet code was added to functions.php- so, now, Wordpress doesn't remove formatted HTML anymore:

```
function uncoverwp_tiny_mce_fix( $init )
{
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'div[*]';

    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'uncoverwp_tiny_mce_fix' );
```

**2)** By adding the following code, too, the above script is supposed to run on my post (here, for example, post id=123)

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_page ('123')) { 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // My javscript code
        </script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

Everything looks fine and logical, but this method doesn't work. I also deferred the script, but the problem remained. What am I missing here?

Comment: check `console` you will see the error

Comment: Page needs to load. Put code inside DOMContentLoaded event callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: @JoshBonnick done. but still doesn't work, with no error whatsoever on `console`. sounds weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I installed and activated [Advanced Editor Tools](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) plugin; then, from **settings**, checked the box "**Keep paragraph tags in the Classic block and the Classic Editor**". so now Wordpress doesn't strip out HTML tags and lets me insert scripts directly in the text editor.